# Count number of a group array in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to count the number of a group array in the array. Example

```
$arr1 = [61,41,41,61,89,90]
$arr2 = [61,41]
$result = 2    //found 61,41 in $arr1  2 time;
```

Or Example

```
$arr1 = [89,61,41,41,61,90]
$arr2 = [61,41,89]
$result = 1    //found 61,41,89 in $arr1  1 time;
```

How to write the code, or concept?

Comment: The second example you provided does not make any sense. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I would have expeceted the second result to be 3

Comment: What if, 1 value appears once and the other appears 3 times would the result be 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you..

```
$arr1 = array(61,41,41,61,89,90);
$arr2 = array(61,41);

$count = array_count_values($arr1); //count values from arr1

$result = array();
foreach($arr2 as $row) {
    $result[$row] = array_key_exists($row, $count) ? $count[$row] : 0;
}

echo min($result);
```

> $arr2 = [61,41] output: 2
>
> $arr2 = [61,41,89] output: 1

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr1 = array(61,41,41,61,89,90);
$arr2 = array(61,41);

$occurrences = min(
    array_count_values(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2)) + array_fill_keys($arr2, 0)
);
```

Arguably a somewhat obscure solution, but a single expression. Returns the number that the entire `$arr2` set occurs in `$arr1`.