# Fix bug : Count number of a group array in array in php

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

from URL : [Count number of a group array in array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537347/count-number-of-a-group-array-in-array-in-php)

I ask question :

```
 $arr1 = [61,41,41,61,89,90]
 $arr2 = [61,41]
 $result = 2    

 //found 61 and 41 in $arr1  2 time; 
 //This mean : found 61 and 41 in $arr1[0] and $arr1[1] 
 //and found 61 and 41 in $arr1[3] and $arr1[2] again
 //So  $result = 2
```

I follow the answer.
That is code:

```
 $arr1 = array(61,41,41,61,89,90);
 $arr2 = array(61,41);

 $count = array_count_values($arr1); //count values from arr1

 $result = array();
 foreach($arr2 as $row) {
    $result[$row] = array_key_exists($row, $count) ? $count[$row] : 0;
 }

 echo min($result);
```

But It have a bug. If I assume

```
 $arr1 = array(5,6,5,6,5,7);
 $arr2 = array(5,5);
 $result = 1; 

 //This mean : found 5 and 5 in $arr[0] and $arr[2]
 // but is'not found 5 and 5 again
```

That true result is 1. but this result is 3. 
Please help me to fix this bug.

Comment: Its working fine. What you suppose to get

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `array-intersect()` and `array_unique()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
$tmp = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
$tmp = array_unique($tmp);
$result = count($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add condition because you have to match two times more in this case

```
  echo ($arr2[0] == $arr2[1]) ? floor($result[0] /2) : min($result);
```